# MySQL command line client is Not installed

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, web

I have installed msi version of mysql from this link.

> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

I have installed all the below.
[image]

I need MySQL command line client but it is not installed and cannot be found either.
What should i do, i have tried other methods but they are not working too.

I need it for a django project.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE/computer? The installer probably added it to your PATH and might need refreshing wherever you're doing your Django stuff.

Comment: yes and also restarted my computer. but still didnt solved.

Answer (score 0):

The old command line client has been replaced my mysqlsh, the MySQL Shell.